# column difference in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

This is my example matrix

```
goog    appl    JPM    BAC    BYD     msft   TIBX
700.30  500.43  43.56  15.34  23.87  32.33   20.44
800.99  600.23  45.33  14.58  32.55  32.45   21.44
750.34  490.22  43.22  16.34  54.22  34.22   19.22 
690.00  540      0     19.45  27.44  36.26   24.54
790.33  650     45.00  18.34  29.47  34.56   23.98
```

I need to create another matrix with the difference of the price from today to the previous day. I tried using `(diff(mat[2,1],mat[2,2])` and then do `sapply` but am not able to get correct results with `diff(mat[2,1],mat[2,2])` gives me numeric(0). Not sure why. Output should have been something like this

```
goog    appl     JPM     BAC    BYD     msft     TIBX
700.30  500.43   43.56   15.34  23.87   32.33    20.44
100.69  99.80    1.84   -0.80   9.55    0.12     1.44
-50.34 -109.99   -2.11   2.34   12.22   0.82    -2.22 
-60.30  49.88    -43.22  3.45   -27.44  2.26     3.54
100.33  90       1.98    2.34   2.47    0.56    -0.98
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `apply`:

**Your Data:**

```
mat <- read.table(text="goog    appl    JPM    BAC    BYD     msft   TIBX
700.30  500.43  43.56  15.34  23.87  32.33   20.44
800.99  600.23  45.33  14.58  32.55  32.45   21.44
750.34  490.22  43.22  16.34  54.22  34.22   19.22 
690.00  540      0     19.45  27.44  36.26   24.54
790.33  650     45.00  18.34  29.47  34.56   23.98", header=TRUE)

rbind(mat[1, ], apply(mat, 2, diff))

##     goog    appl    JPM   BAC    BYD  msft  TIBX
## 1 700.30  500.43  43.56 15.34  23.87 32.33 20.44
## 2 100.69   99.80   1.77 -0.76   8.68  0.12  1.00
## 3 -50.65 -110.01  -2.11  1.76  21.67  1.77 -2.22
## 4 -60.34   49.78 -43.22  3.11 -26.78  2.04  5.32
## 5 100.33  110.00  45.00 -1.11   2.03 -1.70 -0.56
```

Comment: I guess i would have to implement diff seperately. My diff fuction is not working as explained in the question. Can you help with the diff please.

Comment: Then your data doesn't really look like what you say or you have something wrong with your system (you wrote over an R base object or something).  I included the data above that I took from your post and get no such error.

Comment: @greenhorn did you write over the base `diff` function?  If so use `diff <- base::diff` to fix it.

Comment: @Tyler yes it is working now. My actual matrix is pretty big so is there is a cleaner way to read the matrix as a table and not as a text as i have to copy the contents of the bigger matrix in the test field.

Comment: @greenH0rn I only read it in like that because that's how you provided the data.  This should work on the dataset no matter how you read it in.  Maybe you grabbed it directly with some program or used `read.csv`.  Generally the `read.table(text=` is only used to grab data from some place like here but in real use you'd not use the ext argument.

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to call `diff` on the whole matrix.

```
> mm<-as.matrix(read.table(text="goog    appl    JPM    BAC    BYD     msft   TIBX
+ 700.30  500.43  43.56  15.34  23.87  32.33   20.44
+ 800.99  600.23  45.33  14.58  32.55  32.45   21.44
+ 750.34  490.22  43.22  16.34  54.22  34.22   19.22 
+ 690.00  540      0     19.45  27.44  36.26   24.54
+ 790.33  650     45.00  18.34  29.47  34.56   23.98",header=T))
> diff(mm)
       goog    appl    JPM   BAC    BYD  msft  TIBX
[1,] 100.69   99.80   1.77 -0.76   8.68  0.12  1.00
[2,] -50.65 -110.01  -2.11  1.76  21.67  1.77 -2.22
[3,] -60.34   49.78 -43.22  3.11 -26.78  2.04  5.32
[4,] 100.33  110.00  45.00 -1.11   2.03 -1.70 -0.56
```

> 

Comment: So the full answer is `rbind( mat[1,], diff(mat) )`.

Comment: Since `mat` here is a `matrix` and not a `data.frame`, this will also probably be faster than the `data.frame` approach.